# Access to nestes FormArray

Tags: angular

```
export class RegulationComponent implements OnInit {
    regulation: Regulation;
    isCreateNew = false;
    regulationForm: FormGroup;
    itemArray: FormArray;
    paragraphArray: FormArray;


 constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private fb: FormBuilder) {
  this.regulationForm = new FormGroup({
  head: new FormControl(''),
  title: new FormControl(''),
  info: new FormControl(''),
  createdDate: new FormControl(''),
  tableOfContentTitle: new FormControl(''),
  items: new FormArray([
    new FormGroup({
      number: new FormControl(''),
      text: new FormControl(''),
      title: new FormControl(''),
      paragraphs: new FormArray([
        new FormGroup({
          number: new FormControl(''),
          text: new FormControl(''),
          title: new FormControl('')
        })
      ])
    })
  ]),
});
this.itemArray = <FormArray>this.regulationForm.controls['items'];
}
```

This is my form and my questions is: how can i access the "paragraph" array in the "items" array?

Something like

```
this.itemArray = <FormArray>this.regulationForm.controls['items'];
```

only for the "paragraph" array.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
<FormArray>this.regulationForm.get('items.paragraphs');
```

Comment: Yep. I missed that index in the middle. Does yurzui's correction work?